# custom structure in wordpress permalinks shows 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am using windows server for my wordpress blog. I have installed wordpress & if I set permalinks to custom structure then blog directory shows 404 - File or directory not found. If set back to Default then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses an Apache Module for pretty permalinks called mod_rewrite which is "default" on every Apache installation, as you are using a Windows Server (IIS) things don't work just right out of the box.

Have a look here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks (Permalinks without mod_rewrite) theres is quite a lot of information how to enable permalinks (to a certain point) on Windows based systems.